# Why is this command not syncing in the bot - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using discord.py and have a bot using [app_commands.CommandTree](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#commandtree).

When I go to define and add 2 slash commands, 1 syncs and shows up in the UI, the other does not.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

```
async def is_owner(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> bool:
    return interaction.user.id == OWNER_ID

@app_commands.command(name="resyncmessage", description="Checks message sent and posts or edits it")
@app_commands.check(is_owner)
async def resyncmessage(interaction: discord.Interaction, guildId: int, channelId: int, messageId: int):
    logging.debug("Entering resyncMessage():")
    await interaction.response.defer()
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "resyncMessage")
    embedMessage = await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
    await procResyncmessage(guildId, channelId, messageId, embed, embedMessage)
    await embedMessage.edit(embed=embed)

@app_commands.command(name="resync", description="Checks all messages and syncs")
@app_commands.check(is_owner)
async def resync(interaction: discord.Interaction, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    logging.debug("Entering resync():")
    await interaction.response.defer()
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Resync")
    embedMessage = await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
    await procResync(channel, embed, embedMessage)
    await embedMessage.edit(embed=embed)

class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.members = True
        intents.messages = True
        intents.message_content = True
        logging.debug(f"intents={intents}")
        super().__init__(intents=intents)
        self.synced = False
    
    async def on_ready(self):
        logging.debug("on_ready started: {self}")
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        logging.debug("ready.")
    
    async def setup_hook(self):
        logging.debug(f"We have logged in as {self.user}.")
        if not self.synced:
            logging.debug(f"Adding command={resync}, guild={LH}")
            tree.add_command(resync, guild=LH)
            logging.debug(f"Adding command={resyncmessage}, guild={LH}")
            tree.add_command(resyncmessage, guild=LH)
            logging.debug("Starting sync...")
            await tree.sync()
            self.synced = True
            logging.debug("Sync complete.")
        else:
            logging.debug("Already synced.")
        logging.debug("Reboot complete, resync started...")
        await self.resyncTrackers()

client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
client.tree = tree

logging.debug("Running...")
client.run(TOKEN)
```

App log:

```
2024-02-15 20:45:59,308 - root - DEBUG - create_pool:<mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool object at 0x7f43f4e97fd0>
2024-02-15 20:45:59,309 - root - DEBUG - __init__:<MySQLPool.MySQLPool object at 0x7f43f4f8f850>
2024-02-15 20:45:59,590 - root - DEBUG - intents=<Intents value=3276543>
2024-02-15 20:45:59,592 - root - DEBUG - Running...
2024-02-15 20:45:59,593 - asyncio - DEBUG - Using selector: EpollSelector
2024-02-15 20:45:59,595 - discord.client - INFO - logging in using static token
2024-02-15 20:46:00,215 - root - DEBUG - We have logged in as ******.
2024-02-15 20:46:00,215 - root - DEBUG - Adding command=<discord.app_commands.commands.Command object at 0x7f43f1ef4d90>, guild=<Object id=646... type=<class 'discord.object.Object'>>
2024-02-15 20:46:00,215 - root - DEBUG - Adding command=<discord.app_commands.commands.Command object at 0x7f43f1eb33d0>, guild=<Object id=646... type=<class 'discord.object.Object'>>
2024-02-15 20:46:00,215 - root - DEBUG - Starting sync...
2024-02-15 20:46:00,442 - root - DEBUG - Sync complete.
2024-02-15 20:46:00,442 - root - DEBUG - Reboot complete, resync started...
```

And when I am on the server with the bot, this is what I see:

[image: Bot integrations]

And if I try to inspect the slash commands, I can only see /resync, no mention of /resyncmessages.

[image: Slash commands]

How can I add the second slash command into the command tree and have it synced for my guild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncing the `resyncmessage` command failed because its parameters have to be lowercase.

```
@app_commands.command(name="resyncmessage", description="Checks message sent and posts or edits it")
@app_commands.check(is_owner)
async def resyncmessage(interaction: discord.Interaction, guildid: int, channelid: int, messageid: int):
    ...
```

But you should have seen this error

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandSyncFailure: Failed to upload commands to Discord (HTTP status 400, error code 50035)
In command 'resyncmessage' defined in function 'resyncmessage'
  In parameter 'guildId'
  In parameter 'channelId'
  In parameter 'messageId'
```

This would suggest an issue with the parameters. After checking the type annotation, the only problem would have to do with the names.
Since command names must be lowercase, we can only assume the same for its parameters.

This is how I have debugged this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am testing with this now, however, I do not see the error you're mentioning about the sync or parameters anywhere in my log files or terminal.

Comment: And that is exactly my concern, but this is from my own testing with your code.

Comment: I have gone ahead and marked this as an answer. I did some cleanup in my bot, and I updated the params, I didn't notice anything getting added yesterday. Today, I cleared cache and after a bit more fiddling, before that, I was finally able to see the new commands. Since then, I've added a third command following all lowercase characters and it showed up right away.